# LinkButton click doesn't trigger with no javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, button, webforms

Web forms user control generating a LinkButton in PageInit:

```
LinkButton b1 = new LinkButton();

b1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);



public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
//redirects to another page .. (no js defined here or in the ascx surrounding this button)
}
```

Why doesn't this wok when my javascript is disabled, if I used no js at all when creating the button?
How do I prevent this?
Yes this is webforms (sorry, unable to comment below).

Comment: It is difficult with out javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that's how web forms manages its events with the server - as I understand it anyway (correct me if I'm wrong). Use html 5 instead. You can make the page postback to the server at the same url with a query string and then on the server grab the query string. Not the best solution but it works; it will look something similar to this:

In your page:

```
<form id="aForm">
    <button id="abutton" type"submit" formaction="thisPage.aspx?redirect=true">click me</button>
</form>
```

In your page load event on the server:

```
if (IsPostBack) {
    object something = Request.QueryString["redirect"];
    if (something == null) 
       //not redirecting
}
```